# In Excel how do I count rows using a relative reference?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

For each user in SHEET2 how do I count the number of times "x" appears in COL1 on SHEET1?  I tried COUNTIF but I don't know how to use a relative reference, or if that's even possible.

SHEET1

```
USER      COL1
user_a    x
user_a
user_b
user_b
user_c    x
user_c    x
```

SHEET2:

```
user_a    1
user_b    0
user_c    2
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [COUNTIFS()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842):

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A:A,A1,Sheet1!B:B,"x")
```

[image]